# Slow Scroll external website to digital display using a Chromecast

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, chromecast

Long story short, I'm casting a page I built (I'm self taught so please don't be too critical) to a Chromecast using Cast All The Things https://github.com/skorokithakis/catt.  It contains the following....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* IFRAME Scroller script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

//specify path to your external page:
var iframesrc="livescores.htm"

//You may change most attributes of iframe tag below, such as width and height:
document.write('<iframe id="datamain" src="'+iframesrc+'" width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>')

</script>
```

And references:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0054)http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/external.htm -->
<html data-kantu="1"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head><body>

<div id="datacontainer" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 5px; width: 100%;" onmouseover="scrollspeed=0" onmouseout="scrollspeed=cache">

<!-- ADD YOUR SCROLLER CONTENT INSIDE HERE -->

<iframe src="https://digitalpool.com/tournaments/20220124-monday-night-10-ball-tournament/scores?navigation=false" style="border: none;" name="2022/01/19 Wednesday Night 9-Ball Tournament" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="1250px" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!-- END SCROLLER CONTENT -->

</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* IFRAME Scroller script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

//Specify speed of scroll. Larger=faster (ie: 5)
var scrollspeed=cache=3

//Specify intial delay before scroller starts scrolling (in miliseconds):
var initialdelay=500

function initializeScroller(){
dataobj=document.all? document.all.datacontainer : document.getElementById("datacontainer")
dataobj.style.top="5px"
setTimeout("getdataheight()", initialdelay)
}

function getdataheight(){
thelength=dataobj.offsetHeight
if (thelength==0)
setTimeout("getdataheight()",10)
else
scrollDiv()
}

function scrollDiv(){
dataobj.style.top=parseInt(dataobj.style.top)-scrollspeed+"px"
if (parseInt(dataobj.style.top)<thelength*(-1))
dataobj.style.top="5px"
setTimeout("scrollDiv()",40)
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initializeScroller, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initializeScroller)
else
window.onload=initializeScroller

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

It looks great in a browser, but when I cast it using Cast All The Things, it takes forever to load and looks terrible.  Any suggestions?  I've googled until I'm blue in the face, however, because I'm self taught, I'm not even sure if I'm googling the right things to be able to smooth scroll and see something quickly without really long load times.

Any alternate suggestions? Or any suggestions to make this work seamlessly?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely the catt cannot render properly a HTML page with IFRAME Scroller script, like the one in your page (or it requires long time to render and the result is not what you want). You may post this issue so that the programmers can give your further advice / help . See this [link](https://github.com/skorokithakis/catt/issues) . Normally an active open source group may reply your question within a couple of days.

Comment: @KenLee I should have thought of that!  Thanks!  If you have any other thoughts, please let me know!